# C#: Multi element list? (Like a list of records): How best to do it?

Tags: c#

I like lists, because they are very easy to use and manage. However, I have a need for a list of multiple elements, like records.

I am new to C#, and appreciate all assistance! (Stackoverflow rocks!)

Consider this straightforward, working example of a single element list, it works great:

```
public static List<string> GetCities()
{
  List<string> cities = new List<string>();
  cities.Add("Istanbul");
  cities.Add("Athens");
  cities.Add("Sofia");
  return cities;
}
```

If I want the list to have two properties for each record, how would I do it? (As an array?)

E.g. what is the real code for this pseudo code?:

```
public static List<string[2]> GetCities()
{
  List<string> cities = new List<string>();
  cities.Name,Country.Add("Istanbul","Turkey");
  cities.Name,Country.Add("Athens","Greece");
  cities.Name,Country.Add("Sofia","Bulgaria");
  return cities;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `List<T>` can hold instances of any type - so you can just create a custom class to hold all the properties you want:

```
public class City
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Country {get;set;}
}

...

public List<City> GetCities()
{
   List<City> cities = new List<City>();
   cities.Add(new City() { Name = "Istanbul", Country = "Turkey" });
   return cities;
}
```

Comment: Jonesome is new to C#, so I'd like to mention that this (correct) answer also uses [Auto-implemented Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx), which are very handy. Edit: Though what he'd be wanting appears to be a `Country` class that has a `Name` and a `List<string> Cities` (or some such)

Comment: Thank you! This works great!  Chris, thx for the tip. I read the reference you pointed to, and I (largely) get it.

Answer (score 6):

Why is noone mentioning a `Dictionary<>`?

I think it would be easier to use a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx). From what I understand the OP wants to have 2 values related to each other, in this case, a country and its capital.

```
Dictionary<string, string> capitals = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"Istanbul","Turkey"},
    {"Athens","Greece"},
    {"Sofia","Bulgaria"},
};
```

To add "Key,Values" to your dictionary:

```
capitals.add("Lisbon, Portugal");
```

[Other possible ways of adding to dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838476/different-ways-of-adding-to-dictionary)

To iterate through the items inside the dictionary:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in capitals)
{
    // do something with entry.Value or entry.Key
}
```

[What is the best way to iterate over a Dictionary in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary-in-c)

To edit an entry:

```
capital[Lisbon]= "..."
```

Even though creating your own class (or struct I guess) works, if the goal is to create a list that contains 2 values that are related to each other a Dictionary is simpler.

Answer (score 4):

```
public class City
{
    public City(string name, string country)
    {
        Name = name;
        Country = country;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Country { get; private set; }
}

public List<City> GetCities()
{
    return new List<City>{
        new City("Istanbul", "Turkey"),
        new City("Athens", "Greece"),
        new City("Sofia", "Bulgaria")
    };
}
```

If you don't really need a list, and it is unlikely that you do, you can make the return type `IEnumerable<City>`, which is more generic. You can still return a list, but you could also do this:

```
public IEnumerable<City> GetCities()
{
    yield return new City("Istanbul", "Turkey"),
    yield return new City("Athens", "Greece"),
    yield return new City("Sofia", "Bulgaria")
}
```

If then you were to loop over cities until you find the first city in Turkey, for example, or the first city that starts with the letter I, you wouldn't have to instantiate *all* cities, as you would with a list. Instead, the first City would be instantiated and evaluated, and only if further evaluation is required would subsequent City objects be instantiated.

Comment: Your answer is more complete! Good job!

Answer (score 4):

For doing things on the fly, you can use Tuples (in .NET 4.0):

```
List<Tuple<string,string>> myShinyList = new List<Tuple<string,string>> {
    Tuple.Create("Istanbul","Turkey"),
    Tuple.Create("Athens","Greece"),
    Tuple.Create("Sofia","Bulgaria")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<City<string, string, int>> cityList = new List<City<string,string, int>> {
    City.Create("Paris","France", 12000000); // City, Country, population
}

foreach(var v in City)
{
    list.Add([0,0,1])
    Console.Write("First entry: {0}", list[0]);
}
```

Comment: Can you give some explanation ?