# How to make add elements method for dictionary in OOP?

Tags: c#, .net-4.8

I can't find any `.add()` method and I don't know what I can do for this.

```cs
public class MyDictionary<TKey, Tvalue>
{ 
    private MyDictionary<TKey, Tvalue> md ;
    public MyDictionary (int size) 
    { 
       md = new MyDictionary<TKey, Tvalue>(size); 
    }
    public void AddItem(TKey key, Tvalue value)
    { 
      md[key] = value;
    }
}
```

There is red line under `md.[key]` and it says:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] 
>   to an expression of type MyDictionary

Comment: You need to write an [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/indexers). But note that at the moment you'd have a stack overflow as soon as you call your constructor - because it will immediately recurse.

Comment: `md.Add(key, value); ` will solve your problem; to add new item to dictionary you need to pass respective key and value to add method. Method name is `.Add(key, Value);` not `.add(key, value)`

Comment: You realise that your `MyDictionary<TKey, TValue>` doesn't inherit `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` so it won't have the methods that come with a `Dictionary`? So maybe your class declaration should look like this `public class MyDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` ?

Comment: Now its working and thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
{
    this.Insert(key, value);
}
```

[From this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312092/how-to-assign-key-value-pairs-in-a-dictionary)