# What is the difference between Dictionary.Item and Dictionary.Add?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Reading the accepted answer of [**C# Java HashMap equivalent**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273139/c-sharp-java-hashmap-equivalent/1273149#1273149), it literary states:

> *C#'s Dictionary uses the Item property for setting/getting items:*
>
> - *myDictionary.Item[key] = value*
> - *MyObject value = myDictionary.Item[key]*

And when trying to implement it, I get an error when using:

`myDictionary.Item[SomeKey] = SomeValue;`

> Error: CS1061 'Dictionary' does not contain a definition for
>   'Item'

And I will need to use a `myDictionary.Add(SomeKey, SomeValue);` instead same as [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39622760/5890227) and [MSDN - Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) in order to resolve the error.

The code is fine, but out of curiosity am I doing anything wrong? Other than one does not compile, what is the difference between

```
Dictionary.Item[SomeKey] = SomeValue;
```

and

```
Dictionary.Add(SomeKey, SomeValue);
```

**Edit:**

I edited the accepted answer in  [C# Java HashMap equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273139/c-sharp-java-hashmap-equivalent/1273149#1273149). See edition history to know why.

Comment: The later will throw DuplicateKeyException if the dictionary already contains SomeKey, while the former will not. Think of it like AddOrUpdate.

Comment: This first : Dictionary.Item[SomeKey] = SomeValue; is to change a values already in the dictionary.  The other is to add new items to dictionary.

Comment: As for your error, just omit Item, like this: myDictionary[SomeKey] = SomeValue;

Comment: The actual syntax would be `Dictionary[SomeKey] = SomeValue;`.  You don't use the `.Item` property.

Comment: Then [**the accepted answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273139/c-sharp-java-hashmap-equivalent/1273149#1273149) has a typo mistake. Dictionary does not have a definition for `item`. Thank you

Comment: @OleksandrPshenychnyy It literally states `C#` and `Item` Property.

Comment: Well it's not exactly a typo, because indexer ([] <- this one) is really compiled to a property named 'Item' (unless stated otherwise), so that other languages are able to access it. You can read more about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx

Comment: @Evk I think you are right. Could you wrap all in a nice answer? Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difference is simple

```
Dictionary[SomeKey] = SomeValue; // if key exists already - update, otherwise add
Dictionary.Add(SomeKey, SomeValue); // if key exists already - throw exception, otherwise add
```

As for the error

```
Error: CS1061 'Dictionary' does not contain a definition for 'Item'
```

C# allows for "default" indexer, but how it should be implemented internally? Remember that there are many languages working with CLR, not just C#, and they would also need a way to call that indexer.

CLR has properties, and it also allows to provide arguments when those properties getters or setters are called, because properties are really compiled as a pair of get_PropertyName() and set_PropertyName() methods. So, indexer can be represented by a property which getter and setter accept additional arguments.

Now, there cannot be property without a name, so we need to choose a name for the property which represents our indexer. By default, "Item" property is used for the indexer property, but you can overwrite it with [IndexerNameAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.indexernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

Now when indexer is represented as regular named property, any CLR language can called it with get_Item(index).

That's why in article you linked that indexer is referenced by Item. Though when you use it from C#, you have to use appropriate syntax and just call it as

```
Dictionary[SomeKey] = SomeValue;
```

Comment: I just found this: [Different ways of adding to Dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838476/different-ways-of-adding-to-dictionary) which I think is worth mentioning as an extra for knowing what is the actual difference between the two, despite the error. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the difference is:

- `Dictionary[SomeKey] = SomeValue;` (not `Dictionary.Item[SomeKey] = SomeValue;`) will add new key value pair if the key does not exist, if the key existed, it will replace the value
- `Dictionary.Add(SomeKey, SomeValue);`   will add new key value pair, and if the key already existed, it will throw Argument Exception: An item with the same key has already been added

The example is:

```
try
{
     IDictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

     dict.Add(0, "a");
     dict[0] = "b";  // update value to b for the first key
     dict[1] = "c";  // add new key value pair
     dict.Add(0, "d"); // throw Argument Exception
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
 }
```