# How to Add Data in Dictionary C# with parameter from Model /Object

Tags: c#, dictionary

How to Add Data in Dictionary C# with parameter from Model /Object
Example :
Dictionary<string, ModelItem> countries = new Dictionary<string, ModelItem>();

Code Sample, How to Add Data in Dictionary C# with parameter from Model /Object

Comment: `countries.Add(someStringValue, someModelItem);` ?

Comment: It's hard to recommend a good already-made-post to help you, it's unclear what your actual question is. Right now it just sounds like "how do I add an entry to a dictionary", which is a very fundamental aspect of the dictionary type, so the best I can do is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838476/different-ways-of-adding-to-dictionary

Answer (score 0):

To add in a way that will crash if there is a same key already exists in the dictionary:

```
countries.Add("USA", someModel);
```

To add in a way that will overwrite the existing Value with your new one if a same key already exists in the dictionary:

```
countries["USA"] = someModel;
```

To add in a way that will stop and not add if the same key already exists in the dictionary:

```
bool didAdd = countries.TryAdd("USA, someModel);
```

Or if your .net is old and doesn't have TryAdd:

```
if(!countries.ContainsKey("USA")) countries["USA"] = someModel;
```

---

You can use the bool returned from ContainsKey/TryAdd to decide what to do if the dictionary already contains the object. Perhaps you want to update only some of it:

```
//update or add
if(countries.ContainsKey("USA"))
    countries["USA"].Name = someModel.Name;
else
    countries["USA"] = someModel;
```